# AJOH - what does it mean?

Tags: ajax, rest, atom-feed

I have seen the term AJOH in relation to ATOM, Ajax, JSON, & REST. What does it mean?

Is it Atom JSON Over HTTP? Can't find any good links.

Comment: [African Journal of Oral Health](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/AJOH)? I have never seen this acronym :)

Comment: @brun do you have a reference to where it's used?

Comment: If you look at the 1 answer so far, it was the exact same slide I was looking at that made me ask the question, but I wasn't able to find more info.

Answer (score 1):

As used in [this Java micro-services presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/jamesalewis/java-microservices), yes:

> [atom+json / HTTP (AJOH)](http://www.slideshare.net/jamesalewis/java-microservices/51)

The use of standard Atom and JSON media types means you can use a regular browser or feed reader to monitor; HTTP means you can take advantage of caching and reverse proxies (["they interact via the uniform interface"](http://www.slideshare.net/jamesalewis/java-microservices/50)).

Comment: Is this Atom in a JSON format? or Atom XML with JSON embedded in it? I'm hoping it is the first.

Comment: [Another slide](http://www.slideshare.net/jamesalewis/java-microservices/38) refers to `application/atom+json`. Given the [`+json` structured syntax suffix](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6839) this is, as you suggest, [Atom in a JSON format](http://www.intertwingly.net/blog/2007/01/15/application-atom-json).